# MDX query needed to show off one level

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have calculated my gross profit and wanted to show as a total however, if I run this code it is showing the result of the difference between Income and Cost of Sales with every Account Summary like the following output

[image]

that is very awkward  My requirement is Income and Cost of Sales have to show the account summary but Gross Profit will have to be only total (one line) instead of explored every account summary. Is there any way/any command to do this in MDX?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Total] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Amount]
     ,[Dim Account].[Account Summary].CurrentMember
    ) 
  MEMBER TotalIncome AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Amount]
     ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income]
     ,[Dim Account].[Account Summary].[All]
    ) 
  MEMBER TotalCOGS AS 
    (
      [Measures].[Amount]
     ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Cost of Sales]
     ,[Dim Account].[Account Summary].[All]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Dim Account].[Account Type].[Gross Profit] AS 
    TotalIncome - TotalCOGS 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Total] ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    (
      {
        [Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Cost of Sales]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].[Gross Profit]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Expenses]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Other Income]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Other Expense]
      }
     ,NonEmpty([Dim Account].[Account Summary].[Account Summary])
     ,NonEmpty([Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[2016]&[August])
     ,NonEmpty([Dim Branch].[HierarchyB-T-C].[Branch Code].&[bfy])
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [CubeProfitLoss];
```

Comment: Please help me if you know the trick, i am running out of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution i was looking for. I am really grateful to whytheq - his code helped me to get to this:

```
 WITH 
  MEMBER [Dim Account].[Account Type].[Gross Profit] AS 
    ([Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income])
-([Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Cost of Sales]) 


SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Measures].[Amount] ON 0
 ,
 NON EMPTY 
 (
 {
 ([Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income], 
  [Dim Account].[Account Summary].[Account Summary])
,([Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Cost of Sales], 
  [Dim Account].[Account Summary].[Account Summary])
,([Dim Account].[Account Type].[Gross Profit], 
 [Dim Account].[Account Summary].[All])
  ,([Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Expenses],
[Dim Account].[Account Summary].[Account Summary]) 
  ,([Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Other Income], 
[Dim Account].[Account Summary].[Account Summary])
  ,([Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Other Expense],
[Dim Account].[Account Summary].[Account Summary])

}
 *[Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[2016]&[August]
 *[Dim Branch].[HierarchyB-T-C].[Branch Code].&[bfy]
 )
 ON 1
FROM [CubeProfitLoss];
```

Comment: As a mark of your gratefulness, you should give him a "+1". This encourages people to help others.

Comment: You are right, I did it now. Actually i didn't know much about this stuff. Thanks for letting me know, Saurav

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your script is very close. Why are you including this member in your calculations? `[Dim Account].[Account Summary].[All]`

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Dim Account].[Account Type].[Gross Profit] AS 
    (
      [Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income]
     ,[Dim Account].[Account Summary].[All]
    ) 
  - 
    (
      [Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Cost of Sales]
     ,[Dim Account].[Account Summary].[All]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Dim Account].[Account Type].[Gross Profit V2] AS 
    (
      [Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income]
    ) 
  - 
    (
      [Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Cost of Sales]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Measures].[Amount] ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      {
        [Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Cost of Sales]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].[Gross Profit]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].[Gross Profit V2]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Expenses]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Other Income]
       ,[Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Other Expense]
      }
     *[Dim Account].[Account Summary].[Account Summary]
     *[Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[2016]&[August]
     *[Dim Branch].[HierarchyB-T-C].[Branch Code].&[bfy]
    ON 1
FROM [CubeProfitLoss];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for at least you replied and tried to find an alternative way however unfortunately it is showing the same result.